# NextJs and dynamic routes - how to handle the empty parameter scenario?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I'm trying to retrieve the url parameter without using query strings, for example, `http://localhost:3000/test/1`, this is what I have so far:

**Dir structure**

```
test
 - [pageNumber].jsx
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Index = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Page number: {router.query.pageNumber}</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

It works, but if I omit the pageNumber param, all I got is a 404 page, an issue we don't have on using query strings.

Now, the question: is it possible to sort this without creating an additional index.jsx page and duplicating code to handle the empty parameter scenario?

Comment: Make a `pages/test/index.jsx` import and export this from all sub pages

Comment: @HMR As easy as it gets. Thank you!

Comment: @HMR can you be more specific? I did not quite get the option you are mentioning and would like to know how it compares to the [Optional catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes)

Comment: @MikeMajara Added answer.

Comment: @HMR neat!! Cheers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see I may as well answer this as I got notified of MikeMajaras comment.

There are several ways of doing this, say you have a route that gets posts from a user and shows 10 posts per pages so there is pagination.

You could use an [optional catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes) by creating `pages/posts/[[...slug]].js` and get the route parameters in the following way:

```
const [user=DEFAULT_USER,page=DEFAULT_PAGE] = context?.query?.slug || [];
```

"Disadvantage" is that `pages/posts/user/1/nonexisting` doesn't return a 404.

You could create `pages/posts/index.js` that implements all code and `pages/posts/[user]/index.js` and `pages/posts/[user]/[page]/index.js` that just export from `pages/posts/index.js`

```
export { default, getServerSideProps } from '../index';
```

You get the query parameters with:

```
const {user=DEFAULT_USER,page=DEFAULT_PAGE} = context.query;
```

You could also just only create `pages/posts/[user]/[page]/index.js` and implement all code in that one and config a [redirect](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects)

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/posts',
        destination: `/posts/DEFAULT_USER`,
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: '/posts/:user',
        destination: `/posts/:user/DEFAULT_PAGE`,
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```